# Как вывести все даты в заданном диапазоне дат

Tags: php, сравнение

Задан диапазон дат. Н-р: 2013-11-04 и 2013-11-20. Как вывести в строку все даты между ними с проверкой на существование этих дат?

Comment: Какое такое существование? Где?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить все даты в диапазоне используйте [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateperiod.php):

```
$from = new DateTime('2013-04-11');
$to   = new DateTime('2013-04-20');

$period = new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('P1D'), $to);

$arrayOfDates = array_map(
    function($item){return $item->format('Y.m.d');},
    iterator_to_array($period)
);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает.

Comment: А вот еще.
Допустим есть еще две другие даты. К примеру 2013-04-10 и 2013-05-10
Как узнать относится ли каждая из полученных нами дат между первым периодом к периоду вторых дат?

Comment: все, разобралась.

Comment: >все, разобралась.

Замечательно :)