# Как прибавить день к дате в цикле? php

Tags: php

```
do
{
$i=1;
$NDate=strtotime("+1 day");
echo"<h2>".$NDate."</h2>";
} while ($NDate<$KDate);
```

например, $NDate="2013-05-14", а $KDate="2013-05-23"
Как организовать цикл, который проходит столько раз, сколько разница в днях между датами?

Answer (score 2):

Не пишите велосипед. Чтобы получить все даты в диапазоне используйте [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateperiod.php):

```
$from = new DateTime('2013-05-14');
$to   = new DateTime('2013-05-23');

$period = new DatePeriod($from, new DateInterval('P1D'), $to);

$arrayOfDates = array_map(
    function($item){return $item->format('Y-m-d');},
    iterator_to_array($period)
);

var_dump($arrayOfDates);
```

Чтобы получить только количество дней между датами - [`DateTime::diff()`](http://docs.php.net/datetime.diff):

```
$from = new DateTime('2013-05-14');
$to   = new DateTime('2013-05-23');

$diff = $to->diff($from);

echo $diff->days;
```

*По мотивам вопроса [Как вывести все даты в заданном диапазоне дат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/216397/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82)*

Answer (score 0):

Написал, маленькую функцию, пускай быдло код, но работает:)

```
function difference($date1,$date2) {
    $date1 = explode("-", $date1);
    $date2 = explode("-", $date2);

    return $date2['2'] - $date1['2'];
}
$NDate="2013-05-14";
$KDate="2013-05-23";

echo difference($NDate,$KDate); // покажет разницу
```

Comment: Алексей, мне бы надо на каждую дату, которая будет между этими датами, делать запрос в БД, так что мне такой вариант не подойдет(

Comment: Ха-ха, а если вторая дата в другом месяце или в следующем году?

Comment: наверено, я безнадёжно старомоден. Чем вас [DateTime][1] не устраивает? Там уже есть почти всё что нужно.


  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php