# string to date convert problem

Tags: php, mysql, дата, время

I need to parce database hour by hour, but i have proble with cycle:
Нужно пропарсить базу и собрать количество записей по определённым критериям с разбивкой по часам чтобы потом занести в таблицу. Не могу победить цикл...

```
$y_idx=date("Y");
for($m_idx=1;$m_idx<13;$m_idx++)
{
  for($d_idx=1;$d_idx<32;$d_idx++)
  {
    for($h_idx=0;$h_idx<24;$h_idx++)
    {
//     $query="SELECT COUNT(calldate) WHERE calldate like \"(strtodate({$y_idx}-{$m_idx}-{$d_idx}-{$h_idx})%\"";
//     echo $query . '<br>';
$date_1=$y_idx . '-' . $m_idx . '-' . $d_idx . ' ' . $h_idx;
$date_2=date("Y-n-j G",strtotime($date_1));
echo $date_2 . '<br>';
    }
  }
}
```

A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: Нашёл более изящное решение http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/216397/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82

Answer (score 0):

если вопрос всё-таки по поводу *mysql*, то можно воспользоваться подходящими функциями для работы с датой и временем.

в примере приведены отдельно три столбца:

- дата
- час
- «сборный» из даты и часа (без минут)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f2a3/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (d datetime);
insert into t values
   ('2015-12-10 01:10')
  ,('2015-12-10 01:20')
  ,('2015-12-10 02:30')
  ,('2015-12-11 01:10')
  ,('2015-12-11 01:20')
  ,('2015-12-11 02:30')
  ,('2015-12-11 03:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select count(*)
  , date(d)
  , hour(d)
  , date_add(date(d), interval hour(d) hour)
from t
group by date(d), hour(d)
order by date(d), hour(d)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f2a3/2/0)**:

```
| count(*) |                    date(d) | hour(d) | date_add(date(d), interval hour(d) hour) |
|----------|----------------------------|---------|------------------------------------------|
|        2 | December, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       1 |               December, 10 2015 01:00:00 |
|        1 | December, 10 2015 00:00:00 |       2 |               December, 10 2015 02:00:00 |
|        2 | December, 11 2015 00:00:00 |       1 |               December, 11 2015 01:00:00 |
|        1 | December, 11 2015 00:00:00 |       2 |               December, 11 2015 02:00:00 |
|        1 | December, 11 2015 00:00:00 |       3 |               December, 11 2015 03:00:00 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Не в каждом месяце 31 день. Ошибка будет

Comment: @Bald56rus: вроде бы это и есть ответ. Ошибка — в предположении, что в месяце 31 день.

Comment: @NickVolynkin мне показалось что просто голосовать за удаление этого ответа как то не очень, из возможных вариантов выбрал этот, хотя судя по всему не совсем удачную формулировку выбрал. счас удалю этот коментарий, ответ был помечен тревогой из длинны и содержимого